# SoundCloud HTML5 Widget API - Play Not Working in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, api, google-chrome, html5-audio, soundcloud

You can see the player live here:

www.stateofpsychosis.com/media/

The viewable player is a custom player. The default SC player has been shrunk down to a 1x1px iframe so it can't be seen without using the developer tools to make changes to the style.

*This is only a problem on Chrome for Android*

For some reason I can't get the API to actually play the music. The Previous/Next buttons work in the sense that they query and change the info, but they won't play the song either. It does however change the default SoundCloud widget play button to a pause button. It changes the track info. But it just won't actually make any noise. If I make the widget viewable and push anything in the default player (as opposed to the custom one), it seems to work though.

Answer (score 2):

I too, am facing the same issue.

It seems that Chrome for Android restricts the ability to trigger HTML5 audio playing. This is  to protect users from extra data usage on their phones. It seems that triggering the audio to play from a script is not allowed.

You can read more about the issue 
[here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178297)

Hopefully they lift this restriction in the near future.